# When did BIP16 pass the 550/1000 threshold?

Tags: consensus, p2sh

BIP16 says on 01 Feb 2012, if more than 550 out of the previous 1000 blocks include "/P2SH/" in the coinbase, then BIP16 will activate on 15 Feb 2012 ([Source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki)).

BIP16 was later revised. On 15 Mar 2012, if more than 550 out of the previous 1000 blocks include "/P2SH/" in the coinbase, then BIP16 will activate on 01 Apr 2012 ([Source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/46aa2a6bdd5ec512dd2e364b298e6e73c3e61354)).

After searching the coinbase of every block, it looks like the 550 block threshold was reached at Block Height 171,455 on 16/03/2012 22:07:16. Since this is after the evaluation date of 15 Mar 2012, how/why was this considered to pass the threshold by the deadline, when it actually did not?

Any help appreciated. It is driving me nuts :-)